# Spawning a drop down menu at a dynamic location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic table which I created using the DataTables library, in each row of the tables I have a button that when clicked it would open a drop down menu. I want to create the menu on the fly using jQuery but I'm running into the problem of not knowing where I am going to append the code.

Is there a way of appending the code to a location or div where the function was triggered?

At the moment my best solution is to get the X coordinates of the triggered button and create the menu at those coordinates.

HTML of table item & example of desired result.

```
<td><button type="button" onclick="buttonClick(event)"><img src="assets/actionMenu.png"></button></td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you're trying to make what I would generally call a `context menu` with jQuery alone. It's nice to use packages to handle these if available (for reasons I'll explain below) but in this case, and if you're creating it yourself via jQuery, I think the simplest answer is your best answer: add the HTML beside the button in your template so that it exists in every row. You can make the menu hidden by default and then make it visible when the button is clicked on.

This isn't a perfect solution, and you will have to manage in your JS the hiding/showing of the menus and make sure the CSS of the menus looks correct for each row. You will also potentially have to handle edge-cases like, for example, if the menu is opened in the very last row: is there enough space below the row to show the entire menu? Would you have to make it "drop up" instead of "drop down"? Etc.

Comment: I tested the menu using a position absolute and putting it ontop of everything so it shouldn't clash with other buttons. I didn't know what they were called so it was a bit hard to find it. Thanks for telling me! I'll see if I can find some packages that can handle this.

Thank you very much!